# Sqlite3 using in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i developed one iPhone application, in it i used sqlite3 for data storage . it is working

fine in emulator. i have one doubt  that is ,when we install this application in a real iPhone  is it working properly with out any additional process..

i mean  is there any need to install sqlite3 in iPhone separately ?

pls help me ..

thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is compiled directly into your app as a single C file (the *amalgamation*) that you include in the build. This means that there is no library that you need to install separately.

Answer (score 0):

it should be fine, I did not have to do anything weird like installing sqlite3 on the iPhone. Best bet is to get hold on an iPhone and put your application on it and test it. I have heard that some people find something crashes on the iPhone but not on the simlulator so its better to be safe than sorry (note its a simulator not an emulator so it is not going to emulate an iPhone 100%).

Comment: hanks you very much..  
dear Allan .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work fine. But you should consider migrating to Core Data: it provides a powerful way to deal with data without you having to muck around in sqlite.

Comment: True but lots of apps are cross platform even using C++ on the iphone with .mm files or compiling on g++.  While Core Data is great for just iphone or mac platforms, sqllite works on all platforms even consoles (especially if you want to make a cross platform game engine).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the sqlite dynamic library that is installed on the iPhone, how do you guarantee that header file version your app was compiled against is compatible with the dynamic library on the iPhone. This can happen when compiling against a different version of the SDK with differing sqllite versions then what the iPhone has installed.